Why does T-SQL throw error on rounding a specific value
In SQL Server, when I want to execute the following statement, it throws an error
SELECT ROUND(99.9, 0) 

It throws this error:

Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type numeric

Only 99.9 raises this error, except this, every other value produces a valid result.
What is the reason for this?
Expected result should be
100


Quite possibly, it's because whatever holds the value is limited to two digits before the decimal point and thus cannot handle 100.0 ....

The return type from ROUND for decimal(p, s) is again decimal(p, s). In your case 100.0 is numeric(4, 1), not numeric(3,1).

The Remarks section of the documentation explains this; what about the explanation it provides didn't you understand so we can try to elaborate.

If the value is stored in a numeric(4,1) variable or column there's no error. If you use declare @num decimal(4,1)=99.9 then Select Round(@num,0) returns 100.0 which is a numeric(4,1) value - 4 digits, one fractional

Based on the above comments, try to fix it: https://dbfiddle.uk/dY83l170

This has been an interesting thread. I don't believe this behavior exists in any other RDBMS I've worked in (mysql, postgres, snowflake, mariadb, redshift, timescale, oracle, teradata, etc). Odd choice by microsoft.

@JNevill, try Sybase, MSSQL's ancestor.

I agree with JNevill that this is again an odd choice. Why on earth would you build it like this ?

The constant 99.9 is type decimal(3,1) : 3 precision digits with 1 scale digit fixed behind the decimal.
Round will return a value with the same scale and precision as the number to be rounded.  100 wont fit in a decimal(3,1) return value.
You can explicitly cast it so it will fit:
Select Round(cast(99.9 as decimal(4,1)),0)
(result: 100.0)
or
Select Round(cast(99.9 as decimal),0)
(result: 100)
